# How to Count a value in a column if another column with the same row equals to something?

Tags: excel

203. John
204. james
205. john

I want to count a number in the number column if the same row corresponds a spesific name.

For example i want to count how many 202 number that corresponds john.

Comment: Only one `202` number can have `john`.  Are you trying to count the number of occurrences of names?  Have you looked into using pivot tables, which would make this problem much easier?

Comment: have you tried `countif`?

Comment: Countif is not enough. If i was looking for how many 202 in that number column, it can be used. I havent got enough info about pivot tables.  I'll look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a PivotTable to do this.

First make sure your data has column headers (`Number`and `Name` in your example). Select your data, including headers, and choose Insert -> PivotTable. Accept the default settings in the dialog. In the table editor, drag `Name` to "Columns" and `Number` to "Rows". Then drag `Name` into "Values".

Your end result should look like the screenshot below. The number in each cell is the number of times that each combination of name and number occurs.

[image: screenshot of PivotTable]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Click here COUNTIFS](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countifs.php) formula. Assuming in column A numbers available and in coulmn B names available then your formula will be

```
=COUNTIFS(B:B,B1,A:A,A1)
```

Hope this is what you need :)

Comment: I'm using an older version of excel. So this function doesnt work. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Oh sorry i don't know that and thanks for the update:)